# refs nonexistent in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, modal-dialog

I want to trigger a button click programmatically in vuejs with a javascript method and I have the following line to reference it via the ref tag. below is my javascript

`this.$refs.action.click();`

Below is the html for the button

`<button v-show="false" ref="action" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#MonitorModal" />`

Is there a reason this isn't working? I believe it's all declared fine and when I run a console.log on this.$refs I see the action as anfield, but when I try to reference it, I get undefined

[image: Picture of this.$refs]

Comment: which vue version are you using? and please show what the content of `this.$refs`

Comment: I'm using vue 2 and I want the button click to happen in a method triggered by another action

Comment: Try out `this.$refs.action.$el.click();`

Answer (score 0):

the elements are only available after the initial mount of the component
if you are using vue 2 try running your code on `mounted` life cycle hook.

```
mounted() {
  this.$refs.action.click();
}
```

in vue 3 use `onMounted` life cycle hook.

```
const action = ref()

onMounted(()=>{
action.value.click()
}
```

Comment: I'm using vue 2 but I want this to happen in a method well after the initial load of the component.

Comment: as long as the element is present in the DOM it should work normally

Comment: if you could show some code i maybe able to help